# Rails. Get vertically associated data without new queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have `Order` model, that `has_many :order_operations`. OrderOperation create all the time, when order state is changed. I want to show all OrderOperations.created_at for my orders without creating new queries. I used MySQL.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :order_operations

  def change_state new_state
    order_operations.create to_state: new_state
  end

  def date_for_state state_name
    order_operations.where(state: state_name).pluck(:created_at).last
  end

end
```

I know about `includes` and `joins` methods, but on calling `date_for_state` always run new query. Even I remove `where` and `pluck` query will perform too.
I have only one idea to create service object for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a join/include, it caches the results of doing a particular query: specifically, a query to get all of the `order_operations` associated with the `order`.

If you had loaded @order, eager-loading the associated order_operations, and did `@order.order_operations`, then Rails has cached the associated order_operations as part of the include, and doesn't need to load them again.

However, if you do `@order.order_operations.where(state: state_name).pluck(:created_at).last`, this is a **different query** than the one used in the include, so rails says "he's asking for some different stuff to the stuff i cached, so i can't use the cached stuff, i need to make another query".  You might say "aha, but this will always just be a subset of the stuff you cached, so can't you just work out which of the cached records this applies to?", but Rails isn't that smart.

If you were to do

```
@order.order_operations.select{|oo| oo.state == state_name}.map(:created_at).last
```

then you're just doing some array operations and `.order_operations` **will** use the cached records, as it's the same query as the one you cached with `includes`, ie a straight join to all associated records.  But, if you call it on an instance var @order that doesn't happen to have already eager-loaded the associated records then it will be **much less efficient** because it will do a much bigger query than the one you had originally.

In other words:  if you want to get an efficiency gain by using `includes` then the parameters to your `includes` call needs to exactly match the association calls you will make subsequently on the object.